# Yarn dev not working in Next.js 13: Using wasm build of next-swc

Tags: node.js, next.js, yarnpkg

I am developing a next.js 13 app with `app` experimental feature enabled. 
You can checkout the project [here](https://www.github.com/adityanithariya/Charitier-client/). 
On my one device, yarn dev is running properly, but on device, I am having a problem starting the development server, as shown below:

```
$ yarn dev
yarn run v1.22.19
$ next dev
ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
warn  - You have enabled experimental feature (appDir) in next.config.js.
info  - Thank you for testing `appDir` please leave your feedback at https://nextjs.link/app-feedback
warn  - Experimental features are not covered by semver, and may cause unexpected or broken application behavior. Use at your own risk.

info  - Using wasm build of next-swc

Done in 4.46s.
```

I am not able to figure it out, checked on interne but haven't found anything relevant. 
I am using VSCode, Windows, `next.js@13`, `yarn@1.22.19` and `node@18.14.0` for development.

Comment: i had the same problem i was on node@18.15.0 i installed node@18.0.0 and everything works fine again

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall node js and reinstall node js latest version. then restart your pc.

Answer (score 0):

Try to ran cmd or powershell as administrator, cd into the project directory before running `npm run dev`.

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue with `npm run dev` 
i was getting this issue: 
[image] 
**Solved by** upgrading my node version to **18.0.0** (was 16.14)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have also faced the same issue, you only need to upgrade your node version.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue. but the fix is straightforward. just uninstall the node. and go to https://nodejs.org/en/download and download the "Recommended For Most Users" version.

If it's not working restart your PC. and your problem will be solved