# How can I troubleshoot the issue of my next.js app immediately ending when I run 'npm run dev'?

Tags: next.js

Once i run the command `npm run dev` for nextjs app, it runs and terminal ends the process.

```
PS D:\ecommerce> npm run dev

> ecommerce@0.1.0 dev
> next dev

- ready started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
- info Using wasm build of next-swc
PS D:\ecommerce>
```

Comment: What is your current npm and node version? You may be using an unsupported version.

Comment: node is latest- 18.15.0
npm - 9.6.7

Comment: Check if bit of your NodeJS is correct for you machine.
You could also try upgrading your nodejs to 18.16

Comment: A user explains was able to start the server by running as administrator in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75705585/8003058). As you seem to be running this on a windows machine maybe it is worth a shot. Also depending on what Next.js version you are using you may need to downgrade nodejs or upgrade next.js.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.